# Include generated classes and tests into Sonar + Jacoco test coverage report

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I have a Java project built with Gradle with just 1 module.  It generates the code coverage report for most of the classes and tests.  The problem is that I have some generated code, classes+tests, that are not showing in the code coverage report and I'm not being possible to include then.

My build.gradle looks like it:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("no.nils:wsdl2java:0.10")
        classpath 'org.kt3k.gradle.plugin:coveralls-gradle-plugin:2.8.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.0"
    id 'jacoco'
}

apply plugin: 'com.github.kt3k.coveralls'


dependencies {
    compileOnly("org.sonarsource.java:sonar-java-plugin:6.8.0.23379")
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs +=  'build/generated-sources/api/src/main/java'
sourceSets.test.java.srcDirs +=  'build/generated-sources/api/src/test/java'

sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
        property "sonar.sources", "src/main,build/generated-sources/api/src/main/java"
        property "sonar.tests", "src/test,build/generated-sources/api/src/test"
    }
}

jacocoTestReport {

    reports {
        xml.enabled true
    }
}
test.finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
```

I can see the classes on \build\reports\jacoco\test\html\ and the tests on build\reports\tests\test\classes but not in Sonar.

Anyone know how to do it?

Thank you,

Sannon